# Create custom entity for export SecurityUserRole and SecurityUserRoleCondition Dynamics 365 fo

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

i'm trying to create a new Entity for export info about the user roles , i know there is an entity that exports the users but there isn't an entity in the system for export the table that has the relation between user roles and the legal entities that the user can access.

So i created a custom entity for doing that but i'm getting and error telling me that i don't have the cardinality set in the tables which is weird because i'm defining that in the properties.

Here is a screenshot of my entity and the error that is being show:
[image: Screenshot of the custom entity i'm creating]

This is the error message

Error
Path: [AxDataEntityView/SamSecurityUserRole/Metadata/SecurityUserRole/DataSources
/SecurityUserRoleCondition/Relations/QueryDataSourceRelation1/Cardinality]:NotSpecified is not allowed;
the only allowed values are ExactlyOne, OneMore, ZeroMore or ZeroOne for the data source SecurityUserRole
table SecurityUserRoleCondition relation Relation_SecurityUserRoleCondition1 cardinality..

So my question is where do i set the cardinality?

Comment: Did you try clicking on the actual relation and checking its properties? The one that says `SecurityUserRole.RecId == SecurityUserRoleCondition.SecurityUserRole`

Comment: In the end we separete the info into two independent entities, from what we found there isn't a cardinality set in the tables at the relations section, also because this tables are from System Documentation we couldn't change anything from there.

Comment: There is an N: N relationship between `Role` and `SystemUser`, it is called `systemuserroles_association`, the table is called `systemuserroles`, this table stored all the relatioinship data.